# C# windows form container menu over child form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a calculator application in C# as an exercise. In this application I have a container with a child form. In the container I have a menu, and when I add a child to the container MDI, I resize the container to fit the child.

My problem is that the menu hide some part of the child - the display of the calculator - and I can't see the numbers.

**Example**:

Container's menu hiding the top of the calculator display:
[image: Container's menu hiding the top of the calculator display]

After manually resizing the application - i can see the top of the display:
[image: After manually resizing the application - i can see the top of the display]

How can I set that the first position available in the container's MDI to put childs is - is under the menu ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you Anchor properties are set properly for each control - they are the key to be able to resize a form and have things act as you want.

Comment: If this is homework I've already said enough... Play with the anchors and see what happens when you resize the form.

Answer (score 0):

To start with you don´t need any MDI to have that simple interface. Use a single form, and user UserControl´s for everything else.

**UPDATE**

Create one UserControl for each of the calculators the assign each type to the menu item click, e.g.: remove or hide the controls.

Comment: I do need it because i have to kinds of calculators that switches through the menu

Comment: No you don't, like I said you should used usercontrols and switch between them, no need to use MDI whatsoever.

Comment: Ok I see, but still I don't really understand the question.

Comment: It seems to me that the textbox is shrinking to fit the main form size no?

Comment: Its not shrinking. the part that display the 99999 i hidden under the menu. When i resize the container it fix

Comment: Did you set this properties: FormBorderStyle.None and DockStyle.Fill; and the menu is always top most component.